# OpenCV Python Contour Approximation

Tags: opencv, contour

I want to detect a rectangle shape in the digital meter, to detect the shape contour approximation, but not able to find the exact contour of rectangle .I don't know where is the mistake .please have a look and suggest

[digitalMeter.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOXRl.jpg)

[required-Output-digitalMeter-contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2xmw.jpg)

```py
    import imutils
    import cv2
    
   
    image = cv2.imread('C:\\digitalMeter.jpg')
    
    image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)
    
    
        cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
        displayCnt = None
        
       
        for c in (cnts):
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
          
            if len(approx) == 4:
                print(displayCnt)[enter image description here][2]
                displayCnt = approx
                break
        
        cv2.drawContours(image, [displayCnt], -1, (0, 230, 255), 6)
        cv2.imshow('cnts', image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Apply morphology to clean up the threshold image
- Invert so that the meter is white on a black background
- Find the contours and extract the largest (actually only) contour
- Draw the contour on the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('digital_meter.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply close and open morphology
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((11,11), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# invert
mask = 255 - mask

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw green contour on input
contour_img = img.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contour_img,[big_contour],0,(0,255,0),2)

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('digital_meter_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('digital_meter_mask.png',mask)
cv2.imwrite('digital_meter_contour.png',contour_img)
    
# show the images
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("CONTOUR", contour_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned and inverted image:

[image]

Resulting contour on input:

[image]